# How to know that next two hours directory based in container will grow up to maximum available space?

Tags: linux

I have Nginx based in container and its directory with logs and cache.
I want to make alert via `.sh` script which can warn me that with the last-hour-average writing speed there'd be no free space after two hours.

So. How can I calculate average writing speed of the directory and where to know the free and used space insidte the container?

Comment: In general the problem you should be solving is to ensure that you won't run out of space in the first place (for instance by proper (size based) log rotation) rather than alerting you for something that shouldn't but may or not turn into a problem a couple of hours down the line. - Also existing monitoring can probably alert you (and remind you) with a low level alert at for example 85% disk full and a more critical alert at 90% disk full (depending on the size of the volume you can use GB remaining rather than percentages) where how long apart those two alerts are, can determine your urgency

Answer (score 1):

You may use this handy line for testing for free space, just edit the `/var/`-part with your current directory.

```
test $(var=""; for x in `df /var/ | tail -n1 | column -t`; do var=$var'\n'$x; done; echo -e "$var" | tail -n2 | head -n1 | column -s "%" -t) -ge "95" && echo "Alert, more than 95% of diskspace is used!" || echo "All fine"
```